# now.getTime() inside useEffect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gettime

I wanted to record how many time passed until user click the button.
My plan was like: (the time when user enter the page) - (the time when user click the button) = how many milliseoconds passed!

but my code had an bug and error. my useEffect didn't go what I wanted..
It didn't memorized the time when user entered the page.

console said :

> undefined

and when first hit:

> -1611798597788milliseconds passed

(it worked well as I planned when second hit. weird )

here's my code:

```js
const UserTimer = () => {
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(null);
  const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(0);
  const [diff, setDiff] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let now = new Date();
    setStartTime(now.getTime());
    console.log('' + startTime);
  }, []);

  const onClick = () => {
    setEndTime(Date.now());
    setDiff(endTime - startTime);
    setStartTime(endTime);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{diff}milliseconds passed</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click here</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState does not happen synchronously, so you will not see it change instantly. Best to set a variable then use that variable for your math.

Maybe something like this?

```
const UserTimer = () => {
const [startTime, setStartTime] = React.useState(null);
const [diff, setDiff] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const now = Date.now()
  setStartTime(Date.now());
  console.log('' + now);
}, []);

const onClick = () => {
  const endTime = Date.now()
  setDiff(endTime - startTime);
  setStartTime(endTime);
};

return (
  <div>
    <p>{diff}milliseconds passed</p>
    <button onClick={onClick}>click here</button>
  </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `startTime` state is set as `null` here:

```
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(null);
```

So first click it is still `null`, so your `setDiff(endTime - startTime);` returns the negative number. You can try to solve it using:

```
useEffect(() => {
   let now = new Date();
   setStartTime(now.getTime());
   console.log('' + startTime);
}, [startTime]);
```